# Multithreaded Server having connection refused by peer when running a curl command

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

So when I run this code on multiple tabs it works and shows threading ids but when I run the curl command on another computer/device I get a connection refuse by peer error for 80% of the request.
This is the curl command
for i in {1..10}
do
curl "http://(enter ip):8080/home2.html" &
done

[when i run the server on multiple tabs on a different device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5UCA.png)

```
`# import socket module

from socket import \*
import threading
from datetime import datetime

# In order to terminate the program

import sys

# Prepare a sever socket

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', 8080))
serverSocket.listen(1)

def handle(connectionSocket):
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(4096)

        filename = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
        f.close()
        print(f"server-response,{threading.get_ident()},{datetime.now()}")
    
        # Send one HTTP header line into socket
        header = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' + 'Content-Length: ' + str(len(outputdata)) + '\r\n' + 'Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n'
    
        encodedMessage = (outputdata + '\r\n').encode()
    
        connectionSocket.send(header.encode())
        connectionSocket.sendall(encodedMessage) 
    
        # Send the content of the requested file into socket
        
    
        # Close client socket
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        # Send response message for file not found
        connectionSocket.send(("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n").encode())
    
        # Close client socket
        connectionSocket.close()

    while True:
    # Establish the connection
    print('Ready to serve...')
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

    t = threading.Thread(target=handle,args=(connectionSocket,),daemon=True)
    t.start()

# Close server socket

serverSocket.close()

# Terminate the program after sending the corresponding data

sys.exit()
```

Comment: You messed up the indentation in the question. Is the `while True:` inside or outside the `def handle`?